# Making objects in a for loop with 2d char arrays

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to make an ArrayList of objects.

This is my class.

```java
class Student{
    char[][] charArray;
   
    Student(char[][] charArray){
        this.charArray = charArray;
    }
    
    void display(){
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            System.out.println(this.charArray[i/2][i%2]);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's my main.

```java
public class Testy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  
        ArrayList<Student> classrom = new ArrayList<>();
        char[][] board = {{'X','-'},{'-','O'}};        
        
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            char[][] temp = board.clone();
            if(temp[i/2][i%2]!='X'&&temp[i/2][i%2]!='O'){
                temp[i/2][i%2] ='X';
                classrom.add(new Student(temp.clone()));
            }
        }
        
        for(Student i: classrom){
            System.out.println(i);
            i.display();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
test.Student@2d98a335
X
X
X
O
test.Student@16b98e56
X
X
X
O
```

When i expect something like:

```
test.Student@2d98a335
X
X
'-'
O
test.Student@16b98e56
X
'-'
X
O
```

I think it's something with assigning multiple objects parameter to the same place in memory but i don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: can you describe in your own words, what is the goal of this assignment?

Comment: oh, and your problem is that `board.clone()` doesn't work as you expect. Try to avoid `clone` in general, it causes trouble more often than it really helps. (Yes, there are valid scenarios for using it, but very rare. This is not one of it.)

Comment: `board.clone();` is not cloning the *inner* arrays - remember that `char[][]` actually is an array containing `char[]`, so when it is cloned, a new array is created, but it contains the same (reference to) instances as the original array

Comment: I'm making tic tac toe game with miniMax. The code I show here is just an example of what I have.

Comment: I have z class called Position, and one of the parameters is char[3][3] which stores the board's appearance. I would like to make a func that takes the current Position Object and returns a list of possible "next" Position Objects

Comment: And using clone() doesn't change anything. I'm almost 100% sure that the problem is something with memory allocation but I don't know what to do

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. I couldn't have done it without you. It works exactly as I intended.